# Discrete event simulation framework for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, events, simulation

Does anyone have an experience with some discrete event simulation library that could be used in .NET (C#)?

Despite the basic functionality for queing events and dispatching them, it would be fine to have some non-deterministic behavior (e.g. failures simulation).

I have some tips and I am even considering to write my own, but first, I would like to collect some recomendations.

Thanks.

**Additional info:** i'm not looking explicitly for free product, however, the prize matters :) Just to precise the field i need to map, here is the example of a product: http://www.holushko.com/index.html

Comment: Are you looking for free libraries only ?

Comment: No, as I specified in a note, the library is not required to be free. However, it should not be extraordinary expensive :)

Comment: I have this exact question.   What did you decide to do?

Comment: This will be too late for the original poster, but for anyone looking at this question who might be interested, I have recently released an open-source .NET simulation library called NSimulate. http://phillp.github.io/NSimulate/

Answer (score 2):

There quite a few vendors of simulation based products out there, but they will want money and usually lot of it. For example - http://www.solver.com/exceluse.htm as one of many) - this one is excel based, but they provide SDK to it as well.

When I looked at - [COIN - OR](http://www.coin-or.org/) - COmputational INfrastructure for
Operations Research, there was no discrete event simulation framework listed among their projects. This site is the site for operational research to group at and since simulation falls under OR I had a look there.

I think I had a review of Simulation packages somewhere in a hard copy, but they were all paid for products so that may not be an option in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into writing something like the Simula.Simulation system some time ago (just a small feasibility check), and was disappointed by the lack of Fiber (coroutine) support in dotNet. I ended up doing it in Delphi/Win32 because Windows does have Fibers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try MicroSaint.  It is expensive but highly capable.  I have used an earlier version for a very serious, commercial grade analysis project.
Link follows
http://www.maad.com/index.pl/micro_saint